# How to Tell What Installation of Python Terminal is Calling

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python script in Automator, and need to specify the installation of python to be used.  I would like to use whatever is used by default by my terminal.  How can I enter a command into terminal to be told what installation / path for python terminal is using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `which python` will tell you what command is found on the path first; `which -a python` will list *all* Python commands found on your path. See the [`which` manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/which.1.html) for more details.
- `python -V` will tell you what the version is for that command.